# Ormlite does not map Datetime from SQL Server to C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, mapping, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have tried to retrieve some data from my sql server database in a time interval. I got a field in database of DateTime2(7) and in my DAO I got Datetime as type of that field. But I get the following error:
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 1):

Get Ormlite source and step through. Fastest way to see whats going on and if there is a problem you can fix it fast.

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite